# Configure FOSMessage Bundle with ODM (MongoDB) in Symfony2

Tags: mongodb, symfony, symfony-2.3, odm

I am working on connecting FOSmessage bundle with ODM (mongoDB). I have follow

this link  [1]: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/01b-odm-models.md but I am getting  The class 'UserManager\Sonata\UserBundle\Document\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Message\MessageBundle\Document error.

If some one already configure FOSmessage bundle with mongoDB or any other bundle. Please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle) and [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and both configured in mongoDB works well.

You only have to configure with mongoDB both bundles using the documentantion.

[1- Configure FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#b-mongodb-user-class)

[2- Configure FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/01b-odm-models.md)